# how to solve y^2<x^2 y^2>x^2

Tags: education

Can someone help me with the steps how to solve those inequistins?

```
y^2<x^2
My wrong solution:
y^2<x^2 /sqr
y<x or y<-x or -y<x or -y<-x
```

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/eisb5q0pw4

```
y^2>x^2
My wrong solution:
y^2>x^2 /sqr
y>x or y>-x or -y>x or -y>-x
```

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/eisb5q0pw4

I do something wrong becouse I get the same answer for both inequistins.

*Could not find the appropriate tag.

Thanks,
stav

Comment: I assume these are two separate questions. $y^2<x^2$ is equivalent to $|y|<|x|$, whereas $x^2<y^2$ is equivalent to $|x|<|y|$.

Comment: but how you continue?

Comment: I wouldn't bother, but if you like you can say $|y|<|x|$ is equivalent to $-|x|<y<|x|$ and similarly for the other one.

Comment: Isn't |y|<|x| equivalent to y<|x| OR -y<|x| ?

Comment: Take $y=-5,x=4$, then $y<x$ but $|y|>|x|$

Comment: Thats for the respond but I cant see the connection to what I asked in your last respond

Comment: To spell it out in detail, take $x=4,y=-5$. That does not satisfy $|y|<|x|$ but it does satisfy $y<|x|$. So your idea that $|y|<|x|$ is equivalent to $y<|x|$ or $-y<|x|$ must be wrong.